# Defining a circular area for bounds in an Android game

Tags: android, graphics, 2d, collision-detection

I want to make a simple lunar lander varient with asteroids. I've got asteroids, but I'm stumped on how to make them defined areas with bounds that if my ship crosses causes the player to lose. Any tips about defining a circle pixel area? If it helps, I know the exact coordinates of my asteroids.

Thanks for your advice.

(Looking for collision-detection advice)

**Edit:** My personal solution, slightly more verbose but no more helpful than the solution below :)

```
public boolean collisionDetection(double xa, double ya, double ra, double xb, double yb, double rb) {

        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xa-xb, 2) + Math.pow(ya-yb, 2)); 

        if (distance < ra+rb)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: in regard to your personal solution, it is easier to read than the other one given, but using `sqrt()` and `pow()` is likely to be much slower than using `+` and `*`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that, but I suppose it makes sense. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you know the asteroids and ships co-ords and size:

```
float x = Asteroid.X - Ship.X;    
float y = Asteroid.Y - Ship.Y;
float radius = Asteroid.Radius - Ship.Radius;

x *= x;
y *= y;
radius *= radius;

if((x+y) < radius) 
{
   //collision 
}
```

EDIT: my function was wrong sorry, use this one

Thanks LarsH

Comment: why `Asteroid.Radius * Ship.Radius`? Don't you mean `(Asteroid.Radius + Ship.Radius) * (Asteroid.Radius + Ship.Radius)`? In other words, the distance between ship and asteroid is less than the sum of their radii?